# SolrCloud with SSL and Basic Authentication

Tags: ssl, solr, basic-authentication, solr4, solrcloud

Is it possible to configure SolrCloud with SSL and Basic Authentication?

I have configured 3 nodes of Solr in SolrCloud with SSL using this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Enabling+SSL

and I have added authentication and authorization following this:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Basic+Authentication+Plugin, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Rule-Based+Authorization+Plugin

when only SSL is enabled it works.

when only authentication + authorization is enabled it works

when both are enabled I get following stacktrace during startup:

```
2016-06-01 17:19:41.933 INFO  (OverseerStateUpdate-168013962670440512-172.30.92.66:8983_solr-n_0000000079) [   ] o.a.s.c.o.ZkStateWriter going to update_collection /collections/testowa/state.json version: 1350
2016-06-01 17:19:41.935 INFO  (zkCallback-4-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.c.ZkStateReader A cluster state change: [WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:NodeDataChanged path:/collections/testowa/state.json] for collection [testowa] has occurred - updating... (live nodes size: [3])
2016-06-01 17:19:41.937 INFO  (zkCallback-4-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.c.ZkStateReader Updating data for [testowa] from [1350] to [1351]
2016-06-01 17:19:43.557 INFO  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.c.ShardLeaderElectionContext Enough replicas found to continue.
2016-06-01 17:19:43.557 INFO  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.c.ShardLeaderElectionContext I may be the new leader - try and sync
2016-06-01 17:19:43.557 INFO  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.c.SyncStrategy Sync replicas to https://172.30.92.66:8983/solr/testowa_shard1_replica3/
2016-06-01 17:19:43.561 INFO  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.u.PeerSync PeerSync: core=testowa_shard1_replica3 url=https://172.30.92.66:8983/solr START replicas=[https://172.30.182.43:8983/solr/testowa_shard1_replica1/, https://172.30.182.44:8983/solr/testowa_shard1_replica2/] nUpdates=100
2016-06-01 17:19:44.580 WARN  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.u.PeerSync PeerSync: core=testowa_shard1_replica3 url=https://172.30.92.66:8983/solr  exception talking to https://172.30.182.44:8983/solr/testowa_shard1_replica2/, failed
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://172.30.182.44:8983/solr/testowa_shard1_replica2: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized request, Response code: 401</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/testowa_shard1_replica2/get. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized request, Response code: 401</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:545)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:230)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler$1.call(HttpShardHandler.java:198)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler$1.call(HttpShardHandler.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$$Lambda$3.000000003C022970.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
2016-06-01 17:19:44.582 INFO  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.u.PeerSync PeerSync: core=testowa_shard1_replica3 url=https://172.30.92.66:8983/solr DONE. sync failed
2016-06-01 17:19:44.583 INFO  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.c.SyncStrategy Leader's attempt to sync with shard failed, moving to the next candidate
2016-06-01 17:19:44.585 INFO  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.c.ShardLeaderElectionContext There may be a better leader candidate than us - going back into recovery
2016-06-01 17:19:44.585 INFO  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.c.ElectionContext Canceling election /collections/testowa/leader_elect/shard1/election/168013962670440512-core_node1-n_0000000882
2016-06-01 17:19:44.588 INFO  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.c.ShardLeaderElectionContextBase No version found for ephemeral leader parent node, won't remove previous leader registration.
2016-06-01 17:19:44.590 INFO  (updateExecutor-2-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.u.DefaultSolrCoreState Running recovery
2016-06-01 17:19:44.592 INFO  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.c.LeaderElector Joined leadership election with path: /collections/testowa/leader_elect/shard1/election/168013962670440512-core_node1-n_0000000885
2016-06-01 17:19:44.594 INFO  (recoveryExecutor-3-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.c.RecoveryStrategy Starting recovery process. recoveringAfterStartup=true
2016-06-01 17:19:44.597 INFO  (recoveryExecutor-3-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.c.RecoveryStrategy ###### startupVersions=[[1535485004938739712, 1535485004934545409, 1535485004934545408, 1535485004930351104, 1535485004926156801, 1535485004926156800, 1535485004919865346, 1535485004919865345, 1535485004919865344, 1535485004914622464, 1535485004908331010, 1535485004908331009, 1535485004908331008, 1535485004902039552, 1535485004898893824, 1535485004894699521, 1535485004894699520, 1535485004891553792, 1535485004887359488, 1535485004883165185, 1535485004883165184, 1535485004878970880, 1535485004875825152, 1535485004871630849, 1535485004871630848, 1535485004867436544, 1535485004864290816, 1535485004860096513, 1535485004860096512, 1535485004855902208, 1535485004851707905, 1535485004851707904, 1535485004847513600, 1535485004843319297, 1535485004843319296, 1535485004837027841, 1535485004837027840, 1535485004832833538, 1535485004832833537, 1535485004832833536, 1535485004823396353, 1535485004823396352, 1535485004819202048, 1535485004816056321, 1535485004816056320, 1535485004811862016, 1535485004807667712, 1535485004803473409, 1535485004803473408, 1535485004799279104, 1535485004795084801, 1535485004795084800, 1535485004790890496, 1535485004787744768, 1535485004786696192, 1535485004783550464, 1535485004778307585, 1535485004778307584, 1535485004775161856, 1535485004770967552, 1535485004767821824, 1535485004766773248, 1535485004763627520, 1535485004759433217, 1535485004759433216, 1535485004754190337, 1535485004754190336, 1535485004748947456, 1535485004744753153, 1535485004744753152, 1535485004740558849, 1535485004740558848, 1535485004735315968, 1535485004731121664, 1535485004727975936, 1535485004726927360, 1535485004723781633, 1535485004723781632, 1535485004722733056, 1535485004714344448, 1535485004710150145, 1535485004710150144, 1535485004703858689, 1535485004703858688, 1535485004699664384, 1535485004695470080, 1535485004692324353, 1535485004692324352, 1535485004688130048, 1535485004684984320, 1535485004680790017, 1535485004680790016, 1535485004677644288, 1535485004673449985, 1535485004673449984, 1535485004668207105, 1535485004668207104, 1535485004664012800, 1535485004660867072]]
2016-06-01 17:19:44.599 INFO  (coreZkRegister-1-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr x:testowa_shard1_replica3 s:shard1 c:testowa r:core_node1) [c:testowa s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:testowa_shard1_replica3] o.a.s.c.LeaderElector Watching path /collections/testowa/leader_elect/shard1/election/240110433826439197-core_node3-n_0000000884 to know if I could be the leader
2016-06-01 17:19:44.603 INFO  (OverseerStateUpdate-168013962670440512-172.30.92.66:8983_solr-n_0000000079) [   ] o.a.s.c.Overseer processMessage: queueSize: 1, message = {
  "operation":"leader",
  "shard":"shard1",
  "collection":"testowa"} current state version: 38
2016-06-01 17:19:44.607 INFO  (OverseerStateUpdate-168013962670440512-172.30.92.66:8983_solr-n_0000000079) [   ] o.a.s.c.o.ZkStateWriter going to update_collection /collections/testowa/state.json version: 1351
2016-06-01 17:19:44.611 INFO  (zkCallback-4-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.c.ZkStateReader A cluster state change: [WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:NodeDataChanged path:/collections/testowa/state.json] for collection [testowa] has occurred - updating... (live nodes size: [3])
2016-06-01 17:19:44.613 INFO  (zkCallback-4-thread-1-processing-n:172.30.92.66:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.c.ZkStateReader Updating data for [testowa] from [1351] to [1352]
2016-06-01 17:19:47.272 ERROR (qtp1185255965-22) [   ] o.a.s.s.PKIAuthenticationPlugin Exception trying to get public key from : https://172.30.182.43:8983/solr
org.noggit.JSONParser$ParseException: JSON Parse Error: char=<,position=0 BEFORE='<' AFTER='html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-'
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.err(JSONParser.java:356)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.handleNonDoubleQuoteString(JSONParser.java:712)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.next(JSONParser.java:886)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.nextEvent(JSONParser.java:930)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.<init>(ObjectBuilder.java:44)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getVal(ObjectBuilder.java:37)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.Utils.fromJSON(Utils.java:107)
    at org.apache.solr.security.PKIAuthenticationPlugin.getRemotePublicKey(PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java:202)
    at org.apache.solr.security.PKIAuthenticationPlugin.decipherHeader(PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java:155)
    at org.apache.solr.security.PKIAuthenticationPlugin.doAuthenticate(PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.authenticateRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:283)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:198)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
2016-06-01 17:19:47.281 ERROR (qtp1185255965-22) [   ] o.a.s.s.PKIAuthenticationPlugin Decryption failed , key must be wrong
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.util.CryptoKeys.decryptRSA(CryptoKeys.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.security.PKIAuthenticationPlugin.parseCipher(PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java:172)
    at org.apache.solr.security.PKIAuthenticationPlugin.decipherHeader(PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java:159)
    at org.apache.solr.security.PKIAuthenticationPlugin.doAuthenticate(PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.authenticateRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:283)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:198)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
2016-06-01 17:19:47.288 WARN  (qtp1185255965-22) [   ] o.a.s.s.PKIAuthenticationPlugin Failed to decrypt header, trying after refreshing the key
```

Looks like all security plugins are working ok, but when they are all enabled Basic authentication is not using superuser and nodes between themselves cannot communicate. Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out "blockUnknown" property in security.json was the root of all evil. After going through all steps from scratch even simple authentication was not working with this property set. So I decided to make configuration as minimal as it can be and I worked once I removed blockUnknown from security.json.

I am not sure what exactly is wrong with this property, but after a debugging session I spotted possible error. Internal solr nodes communication was failing on fetching public keys of node in a cluster, probably because of this property in connection with authentication. Nodes for some reason were not authenticating.

Anyway... now I have authentication + authorization over SSL and I can block unknown hosts on SSL level. Brawo Ja!

EDIT: I found out today one more thing that is important in context of this issue. Even though collection access is secured, all other urls are not! I missed somehow this from solrCloud wiki page: **All requests w/o credentials will be rejected with a 401 error. Set 'blockUnknown' to false (or remove it altogether) if you wish to let unauthenticated requests to go through. However, if a particular resource is protected by a rule, they are rejected anyway with a 401 error**.. So summing up this property is rather a must. I have created jira issue for this.

Comment: Are you sure that unauthenticated requests are blocked now? [Without the blockUnknown flag, the default behaviour](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8429) (at least pre-5.5) is to let any unauthenticated request through, as long as the endpoint itself isn't specified as protected. Just to be sure. :-)

Comment: well curl does not allow to access my resources without authentication (401), so I assume should be ok. I checked solr sources and blockunknown flag set to false does not mean that you are allowed to access resources. It means that there will be a password challenge. With this flag set to true requests just fail if no auth header provided.

Comment: I found out today one more thing that is important in context of this issue. Even though collection access is secured, all other urls are not! I missed somehow this from solrCloud wiki page: **All requests w/o credentials will be rejected with a 401 error. Set 'blockUnknown' to false (or remove it altogether) if you wish to let unauthenticated requests to go through. However, if a particular resource is protected by a rule, they are rejected anyway with a 401 error.**. So summing up this property is rather a must. I have created jira issue for this.

Comment: Yes, that's why I added the link to SOLR-8429 that discusses this issue and the note :-)

Comment: @PiotrTempes Could you edit your answer to incorporate what you said in your comments?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is now fixed on Solr 6.2.1!

After the upgrade I have now SSL and basic authentication working fine together, with blockUnknown set to true.

Cheers!

Comment: It seems that version `6.3.0` is the best to use now, it fixed the issue, and has similar API as 6.0 ~ 6.2.x, While `6.4.0` seems changed many API, it might broken other plugin or code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a related issue and this post seems like the closest to my issue.
I am unable to login to Solr Admin console using credentials solr/SolrRocks that was setup.

I am using SOlr 6.6 and  Zookeeper 3.4.10 on windows environment.
My issue is that after uploading security.json file using command:

```
  server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli -zkhost localhost:9983 -cmd putfile
  /security.json security.json
```

and enabling these parameters on SOLR:

```
set SOLR_AUTH_TYPE=basic
set SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-Dbasicauth=solr:SolrRocks"
```

the server starts up fine but I am unable to login to the SOLR Admin console.
I get the error: HTTP ERROR 401, Bad credentials"

I have logged detailed step on this issue at another post on this site:

[Solr Cloud with Basic Authentication fails - Unauthorized 401 Error from Solr Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226188/solr-cloud-with-basic-authentication-fails-unauthorized-401-error-from-solr-ad)

One other thing I tried was using "put" command as opposed to "putfile" command. I get a classcastexception on the SOlr server. Not sure how I could resolve the Solr Admin access issue!

Error when using "put" command:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.lambda$createClusterStateWatchersAndUpdate$0(ZkStateReader.java:428)
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader$3.process(ZkStateReader.java:457)
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$3.lambda$process$0(SolrZkClient.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a question. At best it should be a comment on the original.