# Solr Cloud with Basic Authentication fails - Unauthorized 401 Error from Solr Admin

Tags: authentication, solr, authorization, solrcloud

I have setup SolrCloud using Solr 6.6.0 and Zookeeper 3.4.10.
I am trying to setup Basic Authentication as per latest documentation at
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Basic+Authentication+Plugin

Issue is that the authentication does not work. After setup, I am unable to access Solr Admin console as it does not accept the username/password that was setup.

Below are the Steps with detailed info:

1) **Started Zookeeper listening on port 2181**

2) **Started Solr cloud mode connecting to Zookeeper**

```
 solr start -c -s C:/solr-6.6.0_VM1/server/solr/cores -p 8983 -z 
    "localhost:2181";
```

3) **Created security.json file (as per documentation):**

```
{
"authentication":{    
"blockUnknown": true,    
"class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",    
"credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0=    
Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}    
},    
"authorization":{    
"class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",    
"permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",    
"role":"admin"}],    
"user-role":{"solr":"admin"}    
}}
```

4) **Updated solr.in.cmd to enable authenticaiton on SOLR:**

```
set SOLR_AUTH_TYPE=basic
set SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-Dbasicauth=solr:SolrRocks"
```

5) **Uploaded security.json file to Zookeeper:*

```
 server\scripts\cloud-scripts\zkcli -z localhost:2181 -cmd putfile 
    /security.json security.json
```

6) **Restarted SOLR server**

7) **Opened SOLR Admin console**: `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/`

I was asked username/password. I entered solr/SolrRocks
The admin did not accept the password. When I close the login window, it shows "HTTP ERROR 401, Bad credentials"

Any idea why the authentication is not working on Solr? I have tried the steps exactly as documented. Appreciate your help!

Thanks,

Nishant

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-authentication-Error-401-Unauthorized-td4228524.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SolrCloud with SSL and Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577074/solrcloud-with-ssl-and-basic-authentication)

Comment: Thanks Dalton, the links you provided are a bit different to the issue I am facing. In my case I am unable to access Solr Admin console using the credentials that I setup in security.json.

Comment: Same issue, admin panel as well, did you ever figure it out? I find the docs confusing there is no SolrRocks in the credentials, is this a hash of SolrRocks? I thought that was bad docs and put "testing" in credentials block, but that doesn't work....